# JAVA GUI automation tool for eclipse RCP application

Tags: java, eclipse, testng, ui-automation, gui-testing

I need a better suggestion from u all.

I have an application where  eclipse RCP (JAVA) is used for the GUI.

Now i want to automate the GUI testing in java.

I have created a project where i have used

```
"sikuli" to create test for image comparison
 and 
"testng" to run the test cases .
```

But i am facing problem  using sikuli because it needs to take a lots of pictures as there are lots of buttons, checkbox in the gui.

So, it would be better if i get a

```
java tool which can perform "recording" to write test cases 
and i can also be able to integrate the "sikuli api for image comparison" and 
"testng" to it.
```

Is there any such kind of java tool? 
I am looking for suggestion from you.

Thanks

Comment: There are a couple of Eclipse UI testing tools with recording and screenshot feature. I like [Eclipse RCPTT](http://www.eclipse.org/rcptt/), but you can also use [Eclipse SWTBot](http://www.eclipse.org/swtbot/),
 [Eclipse RedDeer](http://www.eclipse.org/reddeer/), ...

Comment: @howlger  can i add testng or sikuli with swtbot or rcptt? To use swtbot i need to create a plugin project and in the rcptt,  i can not integrate testng or sikuli. Rcptt also does not support image capturing or image comparison

Comment: rcptt also has its defined language where i can not write own java code if any necessary

Comment: RCPTT supports [executing of Java code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39488040/6505250) and taking of screenshots of the whole window or selected parts but does not support image comparison. But if you want to use TestNG and writer Java test code, SWTBot might your candidate (it even supports [plain SWT applications](http://blog.vogella.com/2013/01/16/testing-plain-swt-with-swtbot/)).